# Spring Auditing - How does spring insert @CreatedDate and @LastModifiedDate into database automaticaly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to figure out how Spring inserts the `createdDate` and `lastModifiedDate` automatically when auditing is configured. I have looked over the reference docs for Spring Data JPA but they only explain how to configure auditing. So how does this work behind the scenes?

I am asking this so I could insert extra auditing data like IP-Address of the user the same way.

Comment: see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/auditing/AuditingHandler.java

Comment: did you manged to accomplish that task of storing an IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Spring data commons has class ***AuditingHandler***, which is responsible for populating *createdDate* and *lasModifiedDate*.

You should go-ahead check this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/auditing/AuditingHandler.java) for class definiton and check below methods:

1. setDateTimeForNow
2. setModifyOnCreation
3. touchDate